# how to use pm2 to launch strapi with AutoReload on?

Tags: pm2, strapi

i followed the official tutorial and successfully use pm2 to run a small script to launch strapi.

```
const strapi = require('strapi');
strapi().start();
```

But the AutoReload is off, and the admin panel doesn't allow me to  edit any content type? How should i launch with AutoReload on?

strapi has poped up an alert telling me to launch it with "yarn develop" command, but it doesn't go through pm2, and it shot down when i log out my terminal. So i don't think it's the correct way to launch in real use.

Answer (score 2):

If strapi is asking you to use `yarn develop`, it means; you are not in the development environment so you are not able to make changes in Api.

You need to use a special config file in your root folder called **ecosystem.config.js** and you need to set `autorestart: true`.

```js
module.exports = {
  apps : [{
    name: 'nameofyourapp',
    script: 'server.js',

    // Options reference: https://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/application-declaration/
    // args: 'one two',
    instances: 1,
    autorestart: true,
    watch: false,
    max_memory_restart: '1G',
// not production or staging
    env: {
      NODE_ENV: 'development'
    },
    env_production: {
      NODE_ENV: 'production'
    }
  }],

  // deploy : {
  //   production : {
  //     user : 'node',
  //     host : '212.83.163.1',
  //     ref  : 'origin/master',
  //     repo : 'git@github.com:repo.git',
  //     path : '/var/www/production',
  //     'post-deploy' : 'npm install && pm2 reload ecosystem.config.js --env production'
  //   }
  // }
};
```

Then start it with `pm2 start ecosystem.config.js` command

Comment: i believe the argement "autorestart" is for pm2 not for strapi

Comment: It simply doesn't work

Answer (score 2):

to fix auto reload issue use `yarn strapi dev` instead of `yarn strapi`

Answer (score 0):

You can't edit Strapi Content Type in production. You can only do it in development. Check this discussion: https://forum.strapi.io/t/the-autoreload-feature-is-required-to-use-this-plugin-start-your-server-with-strapi-develop/12207/25